# Xcode 5 with iOS 6 SDK: 'UIAccelerometer' is unavailable: not available on OS X

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I try to compile my app against the iOS 6 SDK under Xcode 5. I followed some tutorials how to use old iOS SDK's in Xcode 5: copy the SDK from an old Xcode (4.6.3) into Xcode 5.

Everything seems to be fine, I set the "Base SDK" to "iOS 6.1" and the "iOS Deployment Target" to "iOS 5.0" and download the iOS 6.1 simulator. But I get a lot of errors when I try to compile the app, like `'UIAccelerometer' is unavailable: not available on OS X`

I don't want to build my app for OS X, only for iOS! I checked "Supported Platforms", but it is correcty set to "iOS".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to delete derived data of your application. And clean your app then compile again.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: YES!! Now, everything works! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- close Xcode
- delete contents of the folder /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Xcode -> Product -> Clean
- Xcode -> Product -> Build

Comment: +1 Worked for me by Cleaning the Build Folder (Cmd-Shift-Option-K).