# How to build a LiveCode external for iOS 7?

Tags: livecode

I've been scratching my head on this for a while. I need to build a LiveCode external for iOS 7, but the most recent LiveCode SDK (LiveCodeSDK-R14) only has support through iOS 6.0.

I've followed these instructions (http://livecode.com/developers/guides/externals/), and got to the point that I could see that the LiveCode scripts expect to be able to copy from an LiveCode folder that corresponds with iOS 7 which doesn't exist (RunRev/Components/LiveCodeSDK/components/5_5_3/device-7_0 and simulator-7_0).

I reinstalled iPhoneOS6.1.sdk and set my xcode project to build with this (had to follow these steps - [Xcode 5 with iOS 6 SDK: 'UIAccelerometer' is unavailable: not available on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092243/xcode-5-with-ios-6-sdk-uiaccelerometer-is-unavailable-not-available-on-os-x)).

So, the external builds now. I get a .lcext file whose internals look like this:

```
M Filemode      Length  Date         Time      File
- ----------  --------  -----------  --------  --------------------------
 -rw-r--r--     68440  14-Dec-2013  14:55:08  iOS/External-Device-7_0
 -rwxr-xr-x     19616  14-Dec-2013  14:58:00  iOS/External-Simulator-7_0
 -rw-r--r--     68440  14-Dec-2013  14:46:34  iOS/External-Device-6_1
 -rwxr-xr-x     20040  14-Dec-2013  16:14:54  iOS/External-Simulator-6_1
- ----------  --------  -----------  --------  --------------------------
            176536                         4 files
```

It looks like I should have the libs to load the external on the device and simulator in either iOS 6.1 or 7.0.

### Simulator

When I test in the simulator, the code after I call the external function doesn't run, so I assume it's erroring-out trying to load the external? Any way I can see what's happening here?

### Device

When I build the stand-alone, I get this error -

> performing iOS arvm v7 (or universal) device builds requires the iOS 7.0 SDK platform to be installed (available with XCode 5.0 or later)

But, according to XCode, I have the iOS 7.0 SDK installed.

### Versions

- Xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)
- LiveCode Community Edition 6.5.0 build 3009

Seems like I'm missing something - it shouldn't be this hard to load a simple library. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in a try/catch block to get the details of the error.

```
try
  yourCommand
catch e
  put e
end try
```

Put here does an NSLog so you can look for logs in Console for the simulator or Organizer for device. You will get mostly a list of numbers which you can decipher with [this](http://livecodeshare.runrev.com/stack/712/LiveCode-Error-Lookup).

As for the error you are getting when building device builds it sounds to me like you might not have added Xcode 5 to your mobile support prefs in LiveCode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That pointed me in the right direction. Turns out that my library was getting called. I was just using variables incorrectly in the LiveCode script. Thanks again!